# Granular Data of US Census Population (zip code, block or household)

Tags: usa, us-census

I have analyzed zip code data and block data of us census 2010. But I am unable to find which data is more at a granular level. I want to say that household data is more granular. Where can I find household data if it is more granular?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're asking. "Some are even saying House hold data is more granular data" makes me think that you're asking about the meaning of the word "granular". Or are you asking where to get the data from?

Comment: I mean which data is more granular?

Answer (score 6):

The granularity of the census data is done by design. When the United States Census bureau conducts a sample of a household, they make sure that the granularity is not small enough as to identify individuals at the household level. If there is not enough of a sample at the block group level, it will get aggregated up to the zip code level.

You can read up on data suppression within the American Community Survey here: http://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/technical-documentation/data-suppression.html

Here is an overview of the Data Hierarchy, noting that household data is not available. 
 [image: DataHierarchy]

Answer (score 2):

both of these data sets contain one-record-per-person

united states decennial public use microdata sample

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/united%20states%20decennial%20census%20public%20use%20microdata%20sample%20%28pums%29

american community survey

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/american%20community%20survey%20%28acs%29